# Rails 4.2 - how to turn off I18n error `translation missing` on views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In our Rails 4.2 app views, there is `I18n` error whenever there is no key found in `zh-CN` file:

```
 translation missing: zh-CN.no key
```

Here is in local.rb under config/initializers/:

```
I18n.default_locale = 'zh-CN' if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.development?
```

We would like to turn off this error and prevent it from showing on views. There is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061504/rails-i18n-can-i-turn-off-translation-missing-errors) about the error for Rails 3. However the solutions are not working with Rails 4.2. Also `config.i18n.fallbacks = false/true` does not do the trick.

Comment: For quick solution add Default(EN) text on that file.

Comment: `Emu`, the problem is that the error shows up and pollutes on web page. if we know which translation is missing, then there is no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add **both** a fallback locale and a fallback language.

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

This should force `I18n` to fallback to english. I use it extensively on a Rails 4.1 app, I'm not sure if something changed over it for 4.2 though.

Comment: `@Fire-Dragon-DoL`, put two configs in `environment/production.rb` and the missing translation error is still showing on web page. Just updated the post with config in local.rb

Comment: One note, why are you doing `I18n.default_locale = 'zh-CN' if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.development?` in `local.rb` ? Shouldn't you just default to `I18n.default_locale = :zh` in development.rb **and** production.rb? In addition, I'm 100% sure that `:zh` as default can create a lot of troubles with translation of rails stuff. I suggest you to default to en, and in config (and app controller) set `I18n.locale = :zh` (or `zh-CN`, but test it, not sure if it works). That's your best bet so far, I'm looking into a different solution, meanwhile.

Comment: `@Fire-Dragon-DoL`,Tried again to remove 'zh-CN' or set it to EN in local.rb and moved `zh-CN` to production.rb. Then no translation at all and all back to EN.

Comment: Is there way turning off the `no translation` error? Just make I18n don't show the error.

Comment: Only with things I consider "hacky" (you can google for it, I found only hacky ways)

Answer (score 0):

We can config I18n callbacks in Rails application. For example, when `zh-CN` translation missing, I18n will fallback to `en`. Configuration in my Rails 4.2.2 application like below:

config/application.rb

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
config.i18n.default_locale = :"zh-CN"
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

config/initializers/i18n.rb

```
Rails.configuration.after_initialize do
  I18n.fallbacks.map(:"zh-CN" => :en)
end
```

Reference doc:

1. https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/wiki/Fallbacks
2. http://web.archive.org/web/20151019133539/paulgoscicki.com/archives/2015/02/enabling-i18n-locale-fallbacks-in-rails/